# Is it safe to use a value after a failed formatted extraction?

Tags: c++

It's a relatively simple question, but I couldn't find a clear answer when I was reading through 27.7.2.2.2 [istream.formatted.arithmetic] of the C++ standard, and got lost in all the faucet stuff.

If a formatted extraction (`std::istream >> value`) fails, is it safe to use the `value`? Is the value always unmodified if the extraction fails? For example, is the following code legal and safe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    std::stringstream ss("Hello world!");

    ss >> value; // this will fail

    // will value still be guaranteed to be zero?
    std::cout << "value is " << value << std::endl;
}
```

While [this seems to work in practice](http://ideone.com/5tbWGF), I want some kind of surety.

As a follow up question, what about more complex data types, like `std::string`? Is it safe to use the string (and is its value known) if the extraction fails?

Comment: I believe the semantics have changed in C++14, but you should in general treat target variables as unreadable after a failed extraction. If nothing else that's the *logical* attitude to take.

Comment: does this program terminates? there is no newline after hello world. the input command won't be passed.

Comment: For integral types, they are set to `0`. For character types, they are left initialized. For `std::string`, it is cleared. (At least that what I can ascertain from N3797)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I totally agree that in practice, the value should be treated as unreadable. Unfortunately, sometimes we have to maintain code that doesn't follow best practice, though, and need to know weird things like this...

Comment: Then the only thing you can know is that you cannot know the value. Set it explicitly if you must use it.

Comment: @KerrekSB, AFAIK, things were zeroed in C++11. Is this the change you were thinking of, or was there another one on top of that?

Comment: @chris: I guess so. I thought that was a more recent proposition, but it should be easy to check whether it's already in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

Quick research:
At least on some compilers [the value is reset to default in case of non-empty input string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e409d7079cfe4b3), and [unmodified in case of empty input string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77023acff6fd4cbe), so there is really no guarantee on the `istream` behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 failed input was UB, due to definition in terms of scanf-family (and UB meant that you could not rely on the error reporting either, e.g. hex input with too many digits).

There was an apparent guarantee, but it was voided by the UB.

This was fixed in C++11, using e.g. strtoll.